# Custom Cell in storyboard UITableView not being picked up in ios7 with UITableViewCellStyleDefault

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I add a UITableView in storyboard and then add a a cell to that with my customisations. The cells were coming back blank and after debugging I found that the Cell being created isn't my custom one (I gave the cell a tag of 10 to test this).

My code is below:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];
}

Food *curFood = [self.mealFoods objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

/// Get the labels of cell
UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
UILabel *quantityLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];

descLabel.text = curFood.Description;
quantityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", curFood.Quantity];

return cell;
```

In my last project in ios6 the above worked fine, with the exception that the labels were not in contentview. Either I did something last time that I forgot or now in ios7 I need to do something to make it use my prototype/custom cell?

Comment: Did you put the cell identifier in your custom cell (from storyboard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micantox was correct in his comment. I had missed out setting the Cell identifier in the custom cell in storyboard:

[image: Cell identifier]

In my case my identifier was simply 'Cell'.